# Realm TypeError: item.toJSON is not a function

Tags: react-native, realm

I have the following error

```
TypeError: item.toJSON is not a function. (In 'item.toJSON(index.toString(), cache)', 'item.toJSON' is undefined)
```

The schemes are as follows:

```
export class MaturationCode {
  public static schema: ObjectSchema = {
    name: 'MaturationCode',
    primaryKey: '_id',
    properties: {
      _id: { type: 'string' },
      code: { type: 'string' },
    },
  };
}

export class Maturation {
  public static schema: ObjectSchema = {
    name: 'Maturation',
    primaryKey: '_id',
    properties: {
      _id: { type: 'string' },
      name: { type: 'string' },
      codes: { type: 'list', objectType: 'MaturationCode', default: [] },
    },
  };
}
```

To read the registers I do the following:

```
public openRealm() {
    return new Realm({
      path: 'larvia.realm',
      schema: ['MaturationCode', 'Maturation'],
      schemaVersion: schemaVersion,
    });
  }

const data = realm.objects('Maturation');
```

The statement realm.objects('Maturation') throws the error.
I'm using:

```
"react-native": "0.66.3",
"realm": "^10.24.0"
```

And I don't use react-native-reanimated.

Comment: Doesn't the error speak for itself; `item.toJSON is not a function`? I seems `item` does not have a toJSON function. I am not sure what the structure has to do with that error and `item` is not shown anywhere else in the question so we don't know what that is. I am not finding any reference to `toJSON` in the Realm documentation either. Can you clarify what the issue is?